# It is worth to ask equivalence from an Advanced Studies Diploma to a Master of Advanced Studies in another University?

Tags: masters, engineering

I hold MSc (120 ECTS) and Bsc. (180 ECTS) degrees in Materials Science and Engineering. I also hold an Advanced studies diploma (60 ECTS) in Mechanical Engineering. All this were done in a University in the European Higher Education area. I've read some stuff about the MAS- Master of advanced studies.
So long, I found it to be equivalent to an Advanced studies diploma that I have.

**Questions:**

1. Can I ask equivalence from my Advanced studies diploma to a Master of advanced studies (both in Mechanical Engineering, or course) in another University in the EU?
2. If I do it, do I have anything to earn, in terms of CV? Would it become easier for me to get a job abroad if I get equivalence of my ASD to a MAS in a UK or another country?
3. Can I get a joint degree? I mean, can I keep the ASD I have and earn a MAS degree at another university in the UK, or elsewhere in EU? Will I keep the original diploma? Or I lose it, and I earn it at the new University?
4. How much do I have to pay in terms of administrative fees?

Comment: You can ask, but I expect the answer will be negative. Just because I have a Master's degree doesn't mean I can go around asking random universities to grant me another one on the sole basis that I hold an equivalent degree.